# simple while loop in javascript doesn't respect the limit

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to share my experience with you. I just started a book in order to learn Javascript. It's a bit frustrating at the beginning, I got the chapter about function, closure and recursion, and looks really complicated, but I'll be keeping to work hard since I really would like to learn. (thanks for reading :) )

Now I have a problem with a While loop, I don't understand why it doesn't stop when it reaches the limit 50. Here is the code:

```js
function fib (one, two, end) {
  while(two < end) {
    if (one == 1) console.log(one);
    two += one;
    console.log(two);
    one += two;
    console.log(one);
  }
}

fib(1, 1, 50);
```

The result is the following, and it goes beyond the limit 50:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for asking about such a simple thing! :-)

Comment: Because it doesn't check the condition until it reaches the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

two is < 50 when the last iteration of the loop starts, but two's value is increased within the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Maybe with For could have been easier. I don't understand, I thought that the loop had to stop at 34 since 55 is > than 50, but it went way beyond, adding three results beyond 50, this looks weird to my beginner mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition happens before each execution of the body. You are modifying the value of `two` inside your body and when the loop tries to run again it sees you have exceeded your bounds and stops. This is what happens when your code runs.

Initial values
`one == 1`
`two == 1`

Is two less than 50? Yes, Start loop.
1st run results
`two == 2`
`one == 3`

Is two less than 50? Yes, go again.
2nd run results
`two == 5`
`one == 8`

Is two less than 50? Yes, go again.
3rd run results
`two == 13`
`one == 21`

Is two less than 50? Yes, go again.
4th run results
`two == 34`
`one == 55`

Is two less than 50? Yes, go again.
5th run results
`two == 89`
`one == 144`

Is two less than 50? No, two is now greater than or equal to 50. Stop.

Comment: Thank you Marie, you explained very well, and thanks to you I understood how to follow the loop step by step:

Comment: Glad I could help :) Using something like VS Code or the Chrome debugger (F12) can let you step over the code as it happens and actually watch the logic unfold. It takes some time to learn but it can be indispensable!

Comment: sorry I pressed on return but my message was not finished, I paste what I wrote now here: 

Thank you Marie, you explained very well, and thanks to you I understood how to follow the loop step by step: 

“one = 1 - two = 1”, “one = 3 - two = 2”, “one = 8 - two = 5”, “one = 21 - two = 13”, “one = 55 - two = 34”, “one = 144 - two = 89”.  

The loop checks Two when it's on 34 and it goes on, and soon after it displays the following 89 and 144 on the console, then Two is 89 and the loop ends. It's really nice to understand! Thank you again, you will see me often here with my questions :D